# Generating random binary search trees with the Arbitrary typeclass

Tags: haskell, random, binary-search-tree, quickcheck, arbitrary-values

I am working on a problem set where I must write an arbitrary instance for binary search trees. Here is the code I've written so far:

```
data Tree e = E | N (Tree e) e (Tree e)

insert :: (Ord e) => e -> Tree e -> Tree e
-- assume this is implemented, so I can use it below

instance (Ord a, Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (Tree a) where
    arbitrary :: Gen (Tree a)
    arbitrary = sized gen
      where
        gen :: Int -> Gen a
        gen n =
          frequency
            [
              (1, return E),
--                         vvvvvvvvv problematic vvvvvvvvvv
              (n, return $ insert (4::Int) (gen (n `div` 2)))
            ]
```

I'm unsure of how to get the second line of the frequency list to type check. I can see `gen` returns a `Gen Tree` and `insert` requires a `Tree` for its second argument, but I'm not sure how to restructure the code with that knowledge. It is required I use the `insert` function, however. Another problem is I need to get random element values, but I've put that aside for now and made every new element a `4 :: Int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`` gen (n `div` 2) `` has type `Gen (Tree a)`, so you should `fmap` that tree, so:

```
instance (Ord a, Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (Tree a) where
    arbitrary = sized gen
      where gen n = frequency [
                (1, return E)
              , (n, insert <$> arbitrary <*> gen (n `div` 2))
              ]
```

This will thus generate an `arbitrary` value, then an arbitrary `Tree` with size `` n `div` 2 ``, and then return the result of an `insert` with that arbitrary value for that arbitrary subtree.